# The non-nullable local variable 'newTaskTitle' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

[image][image]

I'm Trying to capture onChanged property value which is comming from my TextField and use it inside my onPressed textButton but it's not working. I've read most of the related issues in stack overflow but none of it actually helping in the problem. Do you have any better suggestion that I should do.

Comment: please provide snippet code as text instead of screenshot image

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized *newTaskTile* before accessing it.
**So, at line 12 instead of:**

```
String newTaskTile;
```

**use:**

```
String newTaskTile='';
```

Comment: If I String newTaskTile=''; then it will use that blank string and it will not use the String that i've just typed just now.

Comment: true, but with late modifier you can use the nullable advantage if exists

Comment: @GoleBook : in the onChange callback of TextField, assign new value to newTaskTile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    late String? newTaskTile;
```

and assign a value on init

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    newTaskTile = 'some value';
  }
```

Comment: If I String newTaskTile='some value'; then it will use that some value string and it will not use the String that i've just typed just now in the TextField.